# Find the exact area of a trapezium in which three sides have length of $8$ and a diagonal has a length $12$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Find the exact area of a trapezium in which three sides have length of $8$ and a diagonal has a length $12$.

I'm trying to use separate the trapezoid into two triangles — one isosceles with sides $8,8,12$ and the remaining one — and use $(1/2)ab\sin C$ and the law of cosines to get the other unknown side of the trapezoid or the angles, but it is not working very well for me.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- find the area $A$ of the triangle with sides $8,8,12$ and then the height of the trapezium $H=\frac{A}4$
- consider the other triangle with side $x,8,12$ and find the main base $x$ (we know $H$)

Comment: would it be $27 \sqrt{7}$?

Comment: What did you obtain for H?

Comment: Umm $3\sqrt{7}$

Comment: by Erone's formula the area of the triangle 8-8-12 should be $\sqrt{14\cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 2}=12 \sqrt 7$ thus H should be $H=A/8=3\sqrt 7/2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot the $1/2$ part?

Comment: ops yes of course! then I fix also in the answer, then with have the correct H and for x ? what do you obtain?

Comment: It should be x=10, then $27 \sqrt 7$ it's ok!

Comment: Sorry but I gave only the hint without solving all the problem and I didn't recognize the mistake for H! Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Let $h$ be the height of the trapezium and $2x$ the unknown base. By Pythagoras' theorem we then have the two equations:
$$
(4+x)^2=12^2-h^2\\
(4-x)^2=8^2-h^2\\
$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first one, we get: $16x=80$.